# how to extend Django Meta classes if classes are in different files?

Tags: django-models

the Django docs say:

```
class CommonInfo(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        ordering = ['name']

class Student(CommonInfo):
    ...
    class Meta(CommonInfo.Meta):
        db_table = 'student_info'
```

But how do I handle this if CommonInfo and Student are in different files?  At the moment, my Student file looks like

```
from CommonInfo import CommonInfo
class Student(CommonInfo):
    ...
    class Meta(CommonInfo.Meta):
        db_table = 'student_info'
```

But that is throwing 'AttributeError:  Type object "CommonInfo" has no attribute "Meta"'

Answer (score 2):

The metaclass used in `Model` strips the `Meta` inner class from the class definition, so it it not available in this manner for further use. Define it as a separate class and assign it to the `Meta` class attribute if you need it elsewhere.

Comment: I thought Django only stripped the Meta inner class off of non-abstract model classes.

Comment: @Erik: It replaces it with a `_meta` attribute, but this only uses the values from the `Meta` inner class and is not directly related to it.

Comment: James Bennet has a good summary of this behavior: http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/nov/04/working-models/